# How to find an element from within an on() handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've inherited Bootstrap's button group, for which I'm expected to integrate into a web site as my top-level navigation bar.

```
<div id='nav-bar' class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      <img src='images/icon1.png'>
      <input type="radio" class='nav-button'>Button One
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      <img src='images/icon2.png'>
      <input type="radio" class='nav-button'>Button Two
   </label>
</div>
```

The rendering and functionality itself is ok, although there seems to be many ways of rendering a button group, I'm told this is the way I must do it.

So I've placed a 'delegated' even handler on the labels.  Why the labels?  Seems that's the only element that generate any click events.  If I try to set it on the image or the input, no matter where I click, I will get no events.

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav-bar label', function() {
   var text1 = $(this).text();
   console.log("Text 1: " + text1);
   var text2 = $(this).find('nav-button').text();
   console.log("Text 2: " + text2);
   var text3 = $(this, 'nav-button').text();
   console.log("Text 3: " + text3);
});
```

So setting the even onto the label's, it works.

But regardless what I try, I can't seem to be able to get the text of the input element itself.  I get a lot of garbage with it, which I'm not sure if it's the other elements or what exactly that garbage is.

When I output it to the console, like shown above, I get something like:

```
Text #: 

      Button One
            (another blank line here)
```

And if I try to set my `window.location.hash` like I would like to do in this handler, I get something like:

```
http://host/context/#%0A      %0A      Button One%0A
```

Are the %0A the new line (NL) or line feed (LF) character?
Where is this garbage coming from?
And how do I target only the input element?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8rxhS/2/ ?

Comment: A radio input does not have it's own text.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8rxhS/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an event handler for the label, you can find the elements inside it with `.find()`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav-bar label', function() {
    var img = $(this).find("img");
    var input = $(this).find("input");
});
```

---

Since a radio input does not have its own text, it is not clear what you're actually trying to accomplish.  The text you are showing next to the radio button is just some text in the label.  It isn't part of the radio button itself.  If you want to obtain that text, it's probably easiest to put it in a span like this:

```
<div id='nav-bar' class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      <img src='images/icon1.png'>
      <input type="radio" class='nav-button'><span class="radioText">Button One</span>
   </label>
   <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
      <img src='images/icon2.png'>
      <input type="radio" class='nav-button'><span class="radioText">Button Two</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

And, then you can fetch it from the label event handler like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav-bar label', function() {
    var radioText = $(this).find(".radioText").text();
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ByR7n/

Comment: Thanks for your handler example and the fact that .text() does not work.  What I'm trying to do is set the URL hash based on the selected button.  Reading your answer reminded me that my text will be I18N in the future and I should not rely on it for the hash, but rather use the id.  So I now use **var id = $(this).find('input').attr('id')** and this works (even for other languages).  I just had to add an 'id' to each of my input elements.

Comment: @Jeach - yes, that is a safer way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

you should find the exact text node to be able to get what you want, try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav-bar label', function() {
   var text1 = $(this).text();
   var txt = $(this.childNodes).filter(function(index,node){return node.nodeType==3;}).text();
   console.log(txt);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '#nav-bar label', function() {
  var text1 = $.trim($(this).text());
  console.log("Text 1: " + text1);

  var text2 = $.trim($(this).find('nav-button').text());
  console.log("Text 2: " + text2);

  var text3 = $.trim($(this, 'nav-button').text());
  console.log("Text 3: " + text3);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, mate, I think you may have misunderstood the question.